# Iterator for ConcurrentHashMap giving strange result

Tags: java, collections, concurrency

ConcurrentHashMap is thread safe. So if am adding any values to map at the time of iterating, it should not consider them. Below is my code:

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>();
    map.put("ONE", 1);
    map.put("TWO", 2);
    Iterator<String> it = map.keySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        String key = (String) it.next();
        System.out.println(key + " : " + map.get(key));
        map.put("9", 10); // This should not be reflected in the Iterator
        map.put("5", 10); // This should not be reflected in the Iterator
    }
}
}
```

### Output:

```
    TWO : 2
    ONE : 1
    9 : 10
```

My question is why iterator considering map.put("9", 10);

Comment: Which JDK version are you using?

Comment: I have tested this code on jdk6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ConcurrentHashMap is thread safe. So if am adding any values to map at the time of iterating, it should not consider them.

That is not correct.  This is what the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) says:

> *"Similarly, Iterators, Spliterators and Enumerations return elements reflecting the state of the hash table **at some point at or since the creation of the iterator/enumeration**."*

Note the "or since"!

And it also says that the iterators are "weakly consistent" which means that:

> *"they are guaranteed to traverse elements as they existed upon construction exactly once, and may (but are not guaranteed to) reflect any modifications subsequent to construction."*

---

In short, you are expecting properties of the iterators that the javadocs plainly do not say that they have.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen..Is there any way that modified element will not be considered?

Comment: There is no way to guarantee it with a ConcurrentHashMap.  (Or AFAIK with *any* of the standard `Map` classes.)

Answer (score 1):

ConcurrentHashMap is *thread safe*, but this is a different scenario.

With a List you can use ListIterator with *ListIterator.Add* which is designed for that.

With HashMap I see two solutions:

> 1. Convert to List and then back to HashMap
> 2. Use an additional HashMap
>    for new elements, after the loop ends, use another loop to add all new
>    elements (not quite elegant, but works!).

With Java 8 you may consider using lambda-expressions to simplify the code.